# Как реализовать деление на 2?

Tags: c#

Допустим у меня есть переменная int N = 19; Если я её поделю на 2 - получится 9,5 и выйдет ошибка (нужно что бы тип переменной оставался int). Есть еще 2 переменные A и B, в которые записывается первая часть числа и вторая часть числа. Допустим N = 19, 19 /2 = 9,5. Но мне нужно, что бы в переменной A было 9, а в переменной B было 10.

Comment: Уточните, какое правило деления вы хотите получить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В целых числах 19 / 2 = 9, а не 9,5.

Отсюда вполне легко реализовать деление:

```
a = n / 2; // a = 9
b = n - a; // b = 10
```

Comment: Спасибо, как-то не додумался)) А вообще привык к Pascal и там 19 / 2 выдавало ошибку

Comment: @JediMan4ik, если хотите отблагодарить - примите ответ галкой слева :)

Comment: Да, знаю) ПРосто в тот момент не мог принять, надо было ждать 1 минуту

Comment: @JediMan4ik: почитайте подробнее про `C#`, здесь у каждого типа может быть своя перегрузка арифметических операторов)